# Android first tab is not initialized

Tags: java, android, json, tabs, tabactivity

I made an android app with a view that has tabs (with TabActivity). Every tab contain a list of data that is parsed from a json web service. I put the action on OnTabChanged method (that call the method that parse the json and return an array) and all works fine (with the exception that the first tab is not initialized when the view is started). If I try to initialize the first tab, with the same code that I used in OnTabChanged, I get a NullPointerException from the array of data that I must to add to viewList. I  don't understand why in one case works perfectlly and in other don't work.
This is the method with that I try to initialize first tab:

```
    public void initializeFirstTab(){
    Cluster cluster= new Cluster();
    cluster= clusters.get(0);       
    venuesName= new String[cluster.getVenues().size()];
    for(Venue ven:cluster.getVenues()){
        venuesName[cluster.getVenues().indexOf(ven)]= ven.getName();    
    }
    venuesList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ItineraryOnDays.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, venuesName));

}
```

How to initialize the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to use actionbar with fragment for tabs